# creating a new user Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, password

I am trying to new user that can sftp on a server....i did this

```
ubuntu@ip-10-112-46-15:~$ sudo useradd jesse -p testPass
ubuntu@ip-10-112-46-15:~$ sudo passwd jesse
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

but when i try to login via sftp I cant get in....am i missing something like adding a group or something

the answer was

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Fort he record, you would find that `adduser` is much easier to use for creating users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I can't get in" isn't terribly descriptive.  What is the error?

Why did you give the user a password, and then change it right away?

The easiest way to debug it is to run sftp in verbose mode:

```
sftp -vv jesse@remotehost
```

You might not have a valid shell, you might have AllowUsers or AllowGroups in sshd_config, you might be giving the wrong password, you might have password logins turned off...on and on.  We need some more info.

Comment: sftp -vv jesse@host -pftplogin
Connecting to 889...
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
Connection closed

Comment: why do is permission denied if i have my password

Comment: i need to give someone ftp access to add files so they wont have the key

Comment: where is teh place to check if password logins is turned off

Comment: You want: "PasswordAuthentication yes" and "UsePAM yes" in sshd_config.